# javascript return an filtered array of objects using .map() from an api response

Tags: javascript, loops, ecmascript-6, promise, axios

I have this array of data which I want to manipulate and return another array of object with only what I need, so I was thinking when I receive the api data it is possible to create an map responses like:

```
const [stateData, setStateData] = useState({stateData:[]});


        Promise.all(promises).then(response => {
                let info = [];
                response.forEach(res => {
                    info = info.concat(res.info);
                });
               
        //and here to add my map:
        
      const myData = info.map(fiterData,index) => {
        return info [
        {"id":fiterData.id},
        {"name":fiterData.name},
        {"name":fiterData.description}
        // and so on ...
        ]
        }
         
     setStateData(info);
            });
```

and afterwards to access like `myData.property` ?
So will work if will be used in this way ?

Comment: Please read [ask], create a [mcve]. Don't let us wonder what is your task, your entry data and what should `setStateData` be.

Comment: Doesn't look like a valid javascript though...If your goal is to return only the "valid" data from each object of the array (aka no extra properties), than your code is close. It would be :`return {id: fiterData.id, name: fiterData.name, description: fiterData.description};` (note, there no `info` or `[ ]` in the return)

Comment: @vanowm yeah, you're right, you can add'it as an elevate answer to get the points